# python office automation over telnet

Tags: python, ssh, telnet, win32com, office-automation

I need to automate some MS Office operations like opening, editing, saving a Excel or Word file. I know this can be done using win32com libraries. I was able to successfully run these scripts from my windows machine where the script resides but I cannot run them in a telnet session to the same windows machine.

```
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\etest\a8n\msoffice.py", line 216, in <module>
    d.save_as('test')
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\etest\a8n\msoffice.py", line 152, in save_as
    self._workbook.SaveAs(filename)
File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 7, in SaveAs
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Office Excel', u'SaveAs method of Workbook class failed', u'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\1033\\XLMAIN11.CHM', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Is this a limitation? Or do you think there might be a mistake in my script?

If this is a limitation, is there any way to automate Office operations and run it over a telnet or a ssh session?

Thanks,

Meghana

UPDATE:

I tried to just open a excel sheet and I got this error,

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Office Excel', u"Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file 'C:\\test.xlsx'. There are several possible reasons:\n\n\u2022 The file name or path does not exist.\n\u2022 The file is being used by another program.\n\u2022 The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.", u'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\1033\\XLMAIN11.CHM', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

But the file wasn't open and was not being used by any program.

Answer (score 1):

My guess (have never tried what you are trying) is that when telnetted in, either the PATH or (more likely) "working folder" is not the same as when logged in. Try using an absolute path for filename. Also ensure that you are logged in using same account for both telnet and desk to run since this affect write permissions.

Also maybe the absence of a desktop has something to do with it. Try setting visibility to false, although that doesn't seem likely sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried again by giving the full pathname. It didn't work this time either.

Comment: I've set the visibility to False. It still shows the same errors. Why does it show this `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\1033\\XLMAIN11.CHM'` in the traceback? Its a help file but I can't open it. Says 'cannot open file'.